# ListView ,OnItemClickListener gives no response

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with a custom baseadapter ,the code for the class and the adapter is as follows

```
   public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 


    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view1, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.linkname); // merchnts name
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imagename); // address
        //TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id); // distance
       // ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mClogo); // logo

        HashMap<String, String> jsn = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jsn = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
       title.setText(jsn.get(Second.Li_nk));
       artist.setText(jsn.get(Second.Image_name));
        //duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(jsn.get(NearBy.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }

}
```

and the class implementing it is as follows

```
    HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("Id",String.valueOf(i));
        map.put(Li_nk,cutsec);
        map.put(Image_name,j4.getString("image_name"));
        mylist.add(map);

    }

    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("loG_tag","Error parsing"+e.toString());
    }



     list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }

        });
   LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(this,mylist);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(false);



}
```

the layout containing the listview is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/zsm" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:clickable="True"
         >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the code for the custom layout for the list is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="True"
        android:focusable="false"


        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
            android:focusable="false"


            android:src="@drawable/merchntlogotitle" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imagename"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"

            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/linkname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imagename"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imagename"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"


            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now setting the onitemclick listener gives no response ,what am I doing wrong ???
I have read plenty of xamples regarding this about setting focus false and others,what am I doing wrong??
Any help would be greatly apprreciated...

Comment: **list.setItemsCanFocus(false);** is this line necessary..

Comment: Read this was recommended in plenty of posts

Comment: @Waqas Yes its showing the items just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following from all the view items in your row's layout, because this stuff is distracting ListView's own item clicking events.

```
android:clickable
android:focusable
```

for example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"

        android:src="@drawable/merchntlogotitle" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imagename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"

        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linkname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imagename"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imagename"

        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set  `android:clickable="True"` in your layouts any where and try it. All click able views are bound with there parents so their parents will not able to get the click event.